# sapply returning repeated instances of first element of vector instead of all elements calculated by custom function in R

Tags: r, function, sapply

Consider the following columns in my dataset:

df$PT : contain strings with repeating pattern. Example:
[1] "60D 0%"  "5M 2%"  "4 2ND M 5%"  ...

df$date : column of dates
[1]  "2021-01-18" "2021-01-18" "2021-01-18" ...

I managed to create a function that reads inputs from the columns above, makes operations with them and returns another date (let's call it date2). The function works fine (I tested it by passing its arguments manually):

function1(PT,date) {
#if/else chain to generate `date2` from `PT` and `date`
#function returns either (date2) or NA according to if/else conditions
}

So far so good. The problem comes when I try to use sapply to apply my function1 for every single term of column df$PT and store the output (which I want to be either a single date or NA for every term in df$PT) in df$new-col, such as:

df$new_col <- sapply(df$PT,function1,date=df$date)

But instead of having the expected output in df$new_col in date format as:

date2a
date2b
date2c
date2d
...

I am obtaining only the first output repeated everywhere, and in string format of a date:
18705
18705
18705
18705
...

What can be going on and how do I solve it to get the correct calculations of date2 in df$new_col?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since your function needs two arguments, you should use `mapply` instead od `sapply` i.e. `mapply(function1, df$PT, df$Date)`

Comment: Spot on!! thank you so much! Is there a smart way for the mapply output to return the value in a date format instead of a string of a date value (18705..) ? Else I will use as.Date(mapply(...)). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because R is vectorized you can create new df columns directly from existing columns.  E.g.:

```
cars <- mtcars
cars$new <- ifelse(cars$cyl == 6 & cars$mpg > 20, "NewVal", NA)
head(cars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb    new
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 NewVal
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 NewVal
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1   <NA>
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 NewVal
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   <NA>
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1   <NA>
```

Comment: That's another way to do it indeed, thanks!!